# To detect whether my phone is jailbroken or not?

Tags: jailbreak, software-update

How would I know whether my iPhone is jailbroken?

If it is jailbroken, would you recommend that I update to a newer version?

Comment: Please ask one question. Also updating depends on a personal preference so there isn't a single answer to that.

Comment: If you can run unsigned code as root, then you're Jailbroken.

Comment: @Harish Surely you would know whether you have jailbroken your own iPhone in the first place ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most simple test is to see if the cydia app is installed.

But that app can sometimes be hidden.

So you could scroll all the way to the left to spotlight search, type in "cydia" if the app comes up, then its jailbroken.

But It could be that the spotlight feature is disabled. In this case your device is jailbroken as well.

Technically I think it would be possible to hide the cydia app even from the spotlight search. But I don't see in any point in doing this. So I think checking for the cydia app is pretty watertight.

Comment: This is an indeterminate way to tell if your iOS device has been Jailbroken.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson then do you have a better way? I don't think this answer deserved a downvote...

Comment: You can install Cydia without being Jailbroken (albeit, it won't function), and Jailbreaking does not require you to install Cydia. If you can run unsigned code as root, then you're Jailbroken. That is one of the few determinate solutions.

Comment: please write an answer if you have a better way